# Do I need a junction box for thermostat wire splices?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, relay

I have an oil fired heating system with 4 zones heated with baseboards. I recently noticed that one of the zones stopped working because its thermostat wire in the basement was frayed. I removed that part of the wire an spliced in a new one. It is 18 gauge wire (2 wires) for a 24V relay. I cannot find any code that specifies:

- whether a junction box is needed
- ... and if so, what type of junction box is required

Has anyone had experience with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If for some reason you don't use a box,  *at least* don't use random twist nuts dangling in air as is so common.  Use UR/UG etc splice connectors and use zip ties for strain relief.   And make sure your splice doesn't drop into a wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NEC says:

> **90.3 Code Arrangement.** This Code is divided into the introduction and nine chapters, as shown in Figure 90.3. Chapters 1, 2, 3, and 4
> apply generally. Chapters 5, 6, and 7 apply to special occupancies,
> special equipment, or other special conditions and may supplement or
> modify the requirements in Chapters 1 through 7.

Assumption is your thermostat control system, like most, is a class 2 control circuit by definition in Article 725. So rules in Chapter 3 apply, as modified by Chapter 7.

Box requirement is found in chapter 3

> **300.15 Boxes, Conduit Bodies, or Fittings - Where Required** ...Where the wiring method is...nonmetallic-sheathed cable, or other
> cables, a box or conduit body shall be installed at each outlet point,
> switch point, conductor splice point, conductor junction point...

So the general requirement is a box is needed for splices, but the Article 725 which modifies chapter 3 articles says:

> **725.3 Other Articles** In addition to the requirements of this article, circuits and equipment shall comply with the articles or
> sections listed in 725.3(A) through (E). Only those sections of
> Article 300 referenced in this article shall apply to Class 2 and
> Class 3 circuits.

300.15 isn't referenced in 725, so a box isn't required.

Answer (score 15):

A junction box is not **required** for low voltage.

However, using a junction box may make the splice more reliable in the long term, by protecting it and securing the wires so it's not stressed.